# Why can't I see my WebView Prefab in Unity game window?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I used [3D WebView](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) in Unity development. I dragged a WebViewPrefab into my scene and clicked 'play'. From the console I knew that it had already loaded the webpage I wanted, but I could't see it in the game window.

I had looked around, but still nothing in the game window.
Could anyone please tell me what had happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem not long ago. I found that WebView doesn't seem to be like those GameObjects we commonly use in unity, it can only be viewed from one direction. This means that if you look at it from behind, you won't see anything. Therefore, you need to adjust your main camera angle.

Also, when you use WebViewPrefab.Instantiate to create your WebView Object, it defaults to a somewhat strange position and angle. I usually set its position manually, and after that, it's easier to find in the game window in play mode.